# Show that $\int{\sec(x)} dx=-\ln|\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2})|+C$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am required to show that $\int{\sec(x)} dx=-\ln|\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2})|+C$

I've tried differentiating both sides of the equation without much luck (the absolute sign is making things complicated):

$\sec(x)=-\frac{1}{|\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2})|}\cdot |\sec^2(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2})| \cdot -\frac{1}{2}$
$=\frac{|\sec^2(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2})|}{2|\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2})|}$

Using the $\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x \tan y}$ property from the get-go doesn't seem to help either.

Would appreciate some hints/tips so that I can head in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute value is irrelevant: the derivative of $f(x)=\log|x|$ is $1/x$ without having to do any particular division into cases. Indeed
$$
\log|x|=\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2)
$$
so the derivative is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot2x=\frac{1}{x}
$$
(You can also do by dividing $\log|x|$ into cases).

Thus you can express the derivative as
$$
-\frac{1}{\tan y}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos^2y}\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=
\frac{1}{2\sin y\cos y}=\frac{1}{\sin 2y}=\frac{1}{\cos x}=\sec x
$$
where I set $y=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}$ for avoiding too complicated formulas.

---

In the direct way, you can do with the substitution $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-2t$, so you get
$$
\int\frac{1}{\cos x}\,dx=\int\frac{2}{\sin2t}\,dt=
\int\frac{\cos^2t+\sin^2t}{\sin t\cos t}\,dt=
\int\frac{\cos t}{\sin t}\,dt+\int\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}\,dt
$$
and finally you find
$$
\log|\sin t|-\log|\cos t|+c=\log|\tan t|+c
$$

Comment: Is there something wrong to warrant a downvote? Perhaps $\sin2(\frac{\pi}4-\frac{x}2)=\cos x$ is too difficult to work out?

Comment: Is any of the answers here wrong?

Comment: @MXYMXY Of course not. I usually avoid the secant trick, because it's generally unneeded, in my opinion. The integral of $1/\sin x$ is a standard exercise, with the substitution $x=2t$ and $1/\cos x$ can be reduced to it by $x=\pi/2-2t$. I upvoted yours.

Comment: I upvoted yours. There seems to be nothing wrong with it. I had the feeling the secant trick was famous, I only saw it 3 days ago and it took me some time to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-t$.

$$\int{\sec(x)} dx=-\int \frac{1}{\sin t}dt=-\int \frac{1}{2\sin \frac{t}{2} \cos \frac{t}{2}} dt =-\int \frac{\frac{1}{2}\sec^2 \frac{t}{2}}{\tan \frac{t}{2}} dx=-\ln|\tan\frac{t}{2}|+C=-\ln|\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2})|+C$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: secx=1/cosx how sin??

Comment: though i havent downvoted

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I substituted $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-t$. $\sec x=\frac{1}{\cos x}=\frac{1}{ \sin t}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $y=\dfrac\pi4-\dfrac x2\implies x=\dfrac\pi2-2y$

$\sec x=\csc2y=\dfrac{\sec^2y}{2\tan y}$

Set $\tan y=u$